# Why are the Real Numbers indecomposable according to Wikipedia?

Tags: constructive-mathematics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposability) claims that

> It follows from the indecomposability principle that any property of real numbers that is decided (each real number either has or does not have that property) is in fact trivial (either all the real numbers have that property, or else none of them do).

Is the property $x>0$ not a counterexample of this? Is wikipedia's definition of indecomposability lacking details?

Comment: How familiar are you with intuitionistic logic, constructive mathematics, and the rejection of the law of the excluded middle?

Comment: Very unfamiliar, to be honest.

Comment: As am I. But the concept of indecomposability belongs over there somewhere.

Comment: The problem is that you're not reading the article in the context of _constructive_ mathematics. $\qquad$

Comment: It's not true *constructively* that every real number $x$ is either $>0$ or $\leq 0$ - you need the law of the excluded middle for that.